# Snap Svg gives an error when removing an element

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Error:

> NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMSVGPathElement.ownerSVGElement]  [*line 1956*]

Code:

```
var g = getG(), node = g.node.firstChild, next;
while (node) {
    next = node.nextSibling;
    selectorLayer.select('#' + node.id).remove();
    node = next;
}
```

Using the above code I am trying to empty the complete `g` tag created using SNAP.SVG

[***Fiddle link***](http://jsfiddle.net/u8yjpcqv/).

The elements gets deleted but then the error starts appearing at a specific interval from `garbage collector` function in snap.svg.js

Comment: is it possible to put up a running example on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Ian I have updated the question with the link

Comment: Do you still get that error here http://jsfiddle.net/u8yjpcqv/1/ ? I couldn't run that on the fiddle, so updated to latest Snap and don't see an error, so not sure if a different version has sorted it, or if its just that I don't see the error anyway. Does the error start happening after anything in particular, or should it be seen on that fiddle as it is ?

Comment: @Ian after clicking on Delete button wait for a while and check the console. The `NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Failure` would be displayed at every specific interval.

Comment: Have tried this on 2 different browsers, and left for 5 mins, and no errors (using the jsfiddle I posted, not the original as I couldn't load that). Have you tried different browsers, and do you have any extensions loaded on them that could be interfering ?

Comment: @Ian you are absolutely correct. Firefox 24.0 gives the above error but works good on latest Firefox 33.0. But if possible, I need to resolve it in Firefox 24.0....? Anyhow thank you for your help.